# Dynamics of RSK

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, robinson-schensted-knuth

There is a way of viewing the RSK correspondence as a map (in fact, bijection) $A \overset{RSK}\longrightarrow \widehat{A}$ from $n\times n$ matrices with entries $\mathbb{N}$ to (weak) reverse plane partitions of shape $n\times n$. See for instance the exposition given here: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~shopkins/docs/rsk.pdf.

Now, since reverse plane partitions of shape $n\times n$ are a subset of the $\mathbb{N}$-matrices, it is possible to consider iterates of this map. Note that the total "mass" in the system is growing unboundedly: we have that $|\widehat{A}| := \sum_{(i,j) \in [n]\times[n]} \widehat{a}_{i,j} = \sum_{(i,j) \in [n] \times [n]} a_{i,j} h(i,j)$, where $h(i,j)$ is the hook-length of the box in position $(i,j)$. So probably one wants to renormalize in some way in order to consider asymptotic behaviour. My question is just whether there is any existing literature on the dynamics of RSK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper "Minuscule reverse plane partitions via quiver representations" by Garver, Patrias, and Thomas (https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08345) does a good job explaining, from the perspective of quiver representations, how the piecewise-linear RSK map is related to another invertible piecewise-linear operation called "rowmotion" (also "promotion"), which does have very interesting dynamics. I think this is the best answer to the vague circle of ideas I was prodding at.

Answer (score 5):

**My original answer was completely wrong.** But I think it was wrong in an interesting way; and I want to use this space to suggest that there is indeed a reasonable question to ask about the dynamics of RSK.

Let $\mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ be the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$. (Actually we can work with $\mathbb{Z}$-fillings of an arbitrary shape $\lambda$, but let's stick to square shapes here.) For $X = (x_{ij}) \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ define

- $\mathrm{rect}(X;i,j) := \sum_{i'\leq i, j'\leq j} x_{i',j'}$;
- $\mathrm{diag}(X;i,j) := \sum_{k=0}^{\mathrm{min}(i,j)-1} x_{i-k,j-k}$;
- $\mathrm{cohook}(X;i,j) := x_{i,j} + \sum_{k=1}^{i-1}x_{i-k,j} + \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} x_{i,j-k}$.

Let $\mathrm{DIAG}\colon \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ be the map that sends the matrix $X = (x_{ij}) \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ to the matrix $Y = (\mathrm{diag}(X;i,j))$. Note that $\mathrm{DIAG}$ is invertible as a map; let $\mathrm{DIAG}^{-1}$ denote this inverse. Define the maps of matrices $\mathrm{RECT}$ and $\mathrm{COHOOK}$ (and their inverses) similarly.

We can extend RSK to a map $\mathrm{RSK}\colon \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ by using the tropical toggle definition due to Pak/Berenstein-Kirillov as outlined in the notes linked to in the question. As pointed out in the question, however, naively studying iterates of $\mathrm{RSK}$ does not really make sense because the mass in the system is growing. So we want to renormalize. One way to do that is to define

$\varphi\colon \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z}) := \mathrm{RECT}^{-1} \circ \mathrm{DIAG} \circ \mathrm{RSK}$

As Darij pointed out in the comments, $\mathrm{RECT}^{-1} \circ \mathrm{DIAG} = \mathrm{COHOOK}^{-1}$, so you can look at $\varphi$ that way if you want. At any rate, I believe the row and column sums of $X \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ and of $\varphi(X)$ agree, so that in particular the mass in the system is preserved under $\varphi$.

The $2 \times 2$ case looks like the following:

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{RSK}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{min}(b,c) & a + b \\ a+c & a + d + \mathrm{max}(b,c) \end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{DIAG}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{min}(b,c) & a + b \\ a+c & a + d + b + c \end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{RECT}^{-1}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{min}(b,c) & a + b - \mathrm{min}(b,c) \\ a+c - \mathrm{min}(b,c) & d - a + \mathrm{min}(b,c) \end{pmatrix}$

So we have $\varphi^2 = \mathrm{id}$ when $n=2$. But already the $3 \times 3$ case exhibits interesting behavior. Let's look at the orbit of the identity map under $\varphi$:

1. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{RSK}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{COHOOK}^{-1}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$;
2. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{RSK}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{COHOOK}^{-1}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$;
3. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{RSK}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{COHOOK}^{-1}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$;
4. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{RSK}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{COHOOK}^{-1}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$;
5. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{RSK}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \overset{\mathrm{COHOOK}^{-1}}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

So the order of $\varphi$ when $n=3$ is at least $5$. In fact, we also have for instance that

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \overset{\varphi}\leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

so the order is at least $10$. The question of course is what is the order of $\varphi$ for arbitrary $n$; indeed, does it have finite order? What is its orbit structure?

Comment: Very nice! Do you have an idea if this (or, rather, the conjugate version $\operatorname{RSK} \circ \operatorname{revrectsum} \circ \operatorname{diagsum}$) could be a (double) evacuation map in disguise?

Comment: OK, it does not look like double evacuation, because it does not act on the two halves of the matrix separately (at least not on the right two halves). But generally it appears to me that $\operatorname{RSK} \circ \operatorname{revrectsum} \circ \operatorname{diagsum}$ is the simpler map. For example, it maps $\left(\begin{matrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{matrix}\right)$ to $\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{y+z}{x} & y \\ z & \frac{w}{y+z} \end{matrix}\right)$ (in the birational setting; to go tropical, replace $+$ by $\min$ and $/$ by $-$).

Comment: Notice that the composition $\operatorname{revrectsum} \circ \operatorname{diagsum}$ has a simple description: It is the inverse of the map sending a matrix $\left(x_{i,j}\right)_{i,j}$ to $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i-1} x_{k,j} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{j-1} x_{i,k} + x_{i,j}\right)_{i,j}$ (now I am back to using your tropical notations). So it can be called "co-hook sum".

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Please see my updated answer. I apologize for claiming $\varphi$ was an involution!

Comment: Oh! So this wasn't a case of "turning around an octahedron" after all? On the upside, that question perfectly fits the upcoming conference.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I think there is still something to flipping the octahedron upsidedown; I will try to understand precisely Example 5 from http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703414.